# Composer Refusing to Use GitHub Branch

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to get Composer to install the 3.0.0 branch of a GitHub project (onelogin/php-saml). However, no matter what I try, it keeps trying to install the master branch version (2.12). Am I missing something? Below is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "munkireport/munkireport-php",
    "description": "Reporting tool for munki",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.5"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.27",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "hautelook/phpass": "^1.1",
        "illuminate/console": "~5.4",
        "illuminate/database": "5.4.36",
        "illuminate/filesystem": "~5.4",
        "league/flysystem": "~1.0",
        "rodneyrehm/plist": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
        "defuse/php-encryption": "^2.1",
        "onelogin/php-saml": "3.0.0-dev"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "adldap2/adldap2": "^8.0 Required for AD authentication"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "munkireport\\models\\": "app/models/",
            "munkireport\\controller\\": "app/controllers",
            "munkireport\\lib\\": "app/lib/munkireport"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
Using version ^2.12 for onelogin/php-saml
```

Comment: Sorry that should be _"onelogin/php-saml": "3.0.0.x-dev"_. I've also tried _"onelogin/php-saml": "dev-3.0.0"_.

Comment: Also looks like its already on Packagist (https://packagist.org/packages/onelogin/php-saml#3.0.0.x-dev), so in theory I should be able to use 3.0.0.x-dev as the version and not need to use GitHub URL at all, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this with the following command:

```
./composer require onelogin/php-saml:3.0.0.x-dev
```